# I got an error: "Extra argument 'progress' in call" when I use AFNetworking in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm trying to using `AFNetworking` in Swift and my code is:

```
self.get(urlString, parameters: parameters, progress: { (progress: Progress) in
    print(progress)
}, success: { (task: URLSessionDataTask, result: AnyObject) in
    print(result)
}) { (task: URLSessionDataTask, error: Error) in
    print(error)
}
```

Then the compiler throws an error:

> Extra argument '`progress`' in call.

I tried to assign `nil` to it, but the error is still there.
What should I do if I don't want to change to Alamofire?

Comment: Type the method again from the beginning and allow Xcode to autocomplete it

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

There are several type mismatches in your code (`URLSessionDataTask` instead of `URLSessionDataTask?`, `AnyObject` instead of `Any?` etc.)

You can get rid of those easily, since closures don't need to have external type specifiers in Swift. Remove all instances of those, e.g. `: Progress`, `: URLSessionDataTask`...

```
self.get(urlString, parameters: parameters, progress: { (progress) in
    print(progress)
}, success: { (task, result) in
    print(result)
}) { (task, error) in
    print(error)
}
```

[Read more about Swift closure syntax here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: That's not true, the following code compiles just fine: `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://google.com")!, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
    
})`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try my best to pay attention to my English grammar later. I am not a native English speaker.